# Return value 3221225725 while scanning two files

Tags: c, scanf, heap-corruption

For input two files "cl-clean-history" and "cd-clean-history" of similar structure of:

```
"Lift Convergence"
"Iterations" "cl"
1     1.14094e+00
2     1.14094e+00
```

and

```
"Drag Convergence"
"Iterations" "cd"
1     0.14094e+00
2     0.14094e+00
```

I want to write a program to read the values in second columns in both files and compute its divisor.
My program code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main (void)
{

  double max_cl_cd, cl_cd_temp;
  int lines_file;
  int tab_line;
  double tab_scan_file[200000][4];


int ch=0;

FILE *result_search_cl;
FILE *result_search_cd;

max_cl_cd=0.0;

if((result_search_cl=fopen("cl-clean-history","r"))==NULL)
{
printf("Unable to open input file\n");  
}
else
{
lines_file = 0;

FILE *result_search_cd = fopen("cd-clean-history", "r");
FILE *result_search_cl = fopen("cl-clean-history", "r");

while (EOF != (ch=getc(result_search_cd)))
    if ('\n' == ch)
        ++lines_file; 


printf("Number of lines in file: %d \n",lines_file);


for (tab_line=0;tab_line<=lines_file;tab_line++) {

  fscanf(result_search_cd,"\n"); 
  fscanf(result_search_cd,"\n"); 

  fscanf(result_search_cd,"%d",&tab_scan_file[tab_line][0]); 
  fscanf(result_search_cd,"\t");
  fscanf(result_search_cd,"%f",&tab_scan_file[tab_line][1]);
  fscanf(result_search_cd,"\n");

  fscanf(result_search_cl,"%d",&tab_scan_file[tab_line][2]);   
  fscanf(result_search_cl,"\t"); 
  fscanf(result_search_cl,"%f",&tab_scan_file[tab_line][3]);
  fscanf(result_search_cl,"\n");




     cl_cd_temp=tab_scan_file[tab_line][3]/tab_scan_file[tab_line][1]; 


           if (cl_cd_temp>max_cl_cd)
           {

            max_cl_cd=cl_cd_temp;
           }
           printf("%f %f\n",tab_scan_file[tab_line][0],tab_scan_file[tab_line][1]);  
    }

    fclose(result_search_cd); 
    fclose(result_search_cl); 
}
printf("%f %f\n",tab_scan_file[tab_line][0],tab_scan_file[tab_line][1]);  
 return 0;
}
```

In my opinion there is something bad in scanf lines, but I don't see what exactly is bad. The first two scans of "\n" are intented to jump two first lines in file. I know that the second option is to perform loop starting from third line (for(tab_line=3; etc.) The %d scans integer value in first column and %f scans float value in second column in both files. Unfortunately, while running in Dev C++ the process exits with return value 3221225725. I found on stackoverflow.com that this value means heap corruption. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you want to process lines, don't use the `scanf()` family for reading the lines.  The couldn't care less about lines.  Read the line using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), then process the line with `sscanf()`.  This will save you pain and grief.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the fscanf [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) again:

Anyway, fscanf accepts as a second argument a format, so something like "%d" (the one you have used some lines later). When you invoke

```
fscanf(result_search_cd,"\n");
```

"\n" is not an identifier. You should replace this line with something like

```
while (getc(result_search_cd) != "\n"); //Skip first line
while (getc(result_search_cd) != "\n"); //Skip second line
```